# javascript / typescript short data type - elasticsearch.js compatibility

Tags: javascript, types, typescript, short

I have a node.js application using javascript (Typescript). I also have an index in elasticsearch that has a field with type 'short'. When I try to write to this from my node.js application, I am trying to store a value using field type 'number', and I get this error message:

> "type":"illegal_argument_exception"
>   "reason":"mapper [metadata.someProperty] of different type, current_type [short], merged_type [integer]"

How can I write to this field from javascript?

Comment: Looking at the [TypeScript Type System](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-system.html) page short is not a basic type also not in [JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx). short must be defined somewhere. Could you give more details regarding the index?

Comment: Some fields store simple enumerations and others counts. I can change the mapping of the index, if that's the best solution. I was just curious to know if there really is no way for elasticsearch.js to write to these field types.